# Track random numbers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, if-statement, random

I want to apply images to 3 random UIButtons amongst my 12 UIButtons in total.

EDIT

Here is the working code;

```
let buttons:NSArray = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12].shuffle()

buttons[0].setImage(UIImage(named: "code1"), forState: .Normal)
buttons[1].setImage(UIImage(named: "code1"), forState: .Normal)
buttons[2].setImage(UIImage(named: "code1"), forState: .Normal)
```

And the working shuffle function;

```
extension CollectionType {
func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
var list = Array(self)
list.shuffleInPlace()
return list
   }
}

extension MutableCollectionType where Index == Int {
mutating func shuffleInPlace() {

if count < 2 { return }

for i in 0..<count - 1 {
    let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
    guard i != j else { continue }
    swap(&self[i], &self[j])
     }
   }  
 }
```

Comment: The answer below should be good, but you should consider using a switch statement also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different idea: throw all 12 `UIButtons` into an array, shuffle that array and the manipulate the first three elements:

```
var buttons = [button1, button2, ..., button12]
buttons.shuffled()

// Do whatever with buttons[0] - button[2]
buttons[0].setImage(UIImage(named: "..."), forState: .Normal)
buttons[1].setImage(UIImage(named: "..."), forState: .Normal)
buttons[2].setImage(UIImage(named: "..."), forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Please update the question with your new approach so we can help you with the new error. @CodeDifferent's approach should work.

Comment: Check your `shuffled` function. My bet is that it's not generic enough to work with elements of all types

Comment: Check my answer below, your array doesn't have an element at index 12. Remove that line and it should work.

Comment: @CodeDifferent Thank you a lot sir, see the edit for the fully working code! You made my day Mr.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (pick3numbers[0] == 1 || pick3numbers[1] == 1 || pick3numbers[2] == 1) {
    //your code here
}
```

Swift's OR operator has two vertical bars instead of just one.

*EDIT:
As per your edit and @Eendje's idea, try:*

```
for i in 1...12 {
    if pick3numbers.contains(i) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it simpler to use `contains`? The method used in the answer is really not practical.

Comment: @Eendje Do you mind posting your idea as an answer? :)

Comment: Your question is too long :p, I'm not exactly sure what you want. I don't mind to post a bit of it as a comment though: `if pick3numbers.contains(1) { // your code }`, this does exactly the same as the answer given by @yesthisisjoe

Comment: I couldn't post the code here but I updated my answer with something inspired by @Eendje that may work

Comment: @yesthisisjoe Everything I put inside of that comes true (//your code) - why do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Because arrays are 0-based, index 12 is out of bounds (you only have twelve objects, indices 0-11)

Remove the line setting the image on `buttons[12]` and it should work.

Comment: Great thanks! Now it runs without errors, but it also sets every button to the new image - not only 3 of them. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Yes, only set the image on the first three elements (index 0 through 2). Because you already shuffled the array, you only need to apply it to three buttons.

Comment: Great, that did the job! Should I check-mark yours or Code Different's answer?

Comment: @CodeDifferent's answer should be marked as the correct answer. Glad it's working for you!